# WiX on Windows XP: Failed to initialize built-in variable value 'ProgramFilesFolder'

Tags: installation, wix, wix3.6

I haveI have an installer built with WiX 3.6 (beta) which works fine on Windows 7, but on Windows XP the install fails.
The end of log file in %TEMP% is:

```
Apply begin
Setting string variable 'ProgressPackageName' to value 'Product'
Error 0x80004005: Failed to get known folder.
Error 0x80004005: Failed to initialize built-in variable value 'ProgramFilesFolder'.
Error 0x80004005: Failed to get variable: ProgramFilesFolder
Error 0x80004005: Failed to set variable value.
Error 0x80004005: Failed to format value '[ProgramFilesFolder]\Company\Product' of variable: InstallFolder
Error 0x80004005: Failed to set variable value.
Error 0x80004005: Failed to format property value.
Error 0x80004005: Failed to add properties to argument string.
Error 0x80004005: Failed to execute MSI package.
Error 0x80004005: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
Error 0x80004005: Failed to execute MSI package.
Error 0x80004005: Failed to execute apply.
Error 0x80004001: UX cannot erase variables by passing a NULL string, yet.
Error 0x80004001: UX cannot erase variables by passing a NULL string, yet.
Apply complete, result: 0x80004005 restart: No
Shutting down, exit code: 0x80004005
```

I haven't found anything on Google about problems with XP and WiX 3.6 (and it seems unlikley that it just wouldn't work with XP, but it is beta after all).

What can I do to try and solve, or at least do to gain more information on what might be going wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a bug in Burn. Please file a bug with details (e.g., version of XP, which build of WiX) at https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=105970&atid=642714.

Comment: Thanks for that, in doing so I realsied I wasn't quite on the latest version - so I thought I should update first. Now I'm on 3.6.1922.0 from this week, it now fails on XP and Win7 with:
`Error 0x8007000d: Failed to load theme controls`
`Error 0x80004005: Failed to create main window`
`Shutting down, exit code: 0x80004005`

Comment: I've filed both bugs reports now.